# How to prove this claim?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

For $x=(x_1,\dots,x_p)$ define  two norms $\|x\|_1=|x_1|+\cdots+|x_p|$  and $\|x\|=\big(\sum_{i=1}^{p}x_{i}^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2} }$. Find the largest constant $a>0$ and the smallest constant $b>0$ such that;
$$
a\|x\|_1\leq\|x\|\leq b\|x\|_1
$$

I have shown $\exists a,b>0$ satisfies this. For instance $b=1$, it holds also, by using

$$
|x_i|\leq\|x\|\Rightarrow \sum_{i}^{p}|x_i|\leq p\|x\|
$$

$a=\frac{1}{p}$, but I got stucked "smallest" and "largest" parts. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which claim is to be proven?

Comment: It is likely that your question will be closed (at least temporarily) unless you edit it to give your thoughts on the problem so far - the current standard comment to explain this is the following:

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: @MattPresland: Thanks for very kind warning!

Comment: You probably have to find the largest $a$ and the smallest $b$ such that $a\|x\|_1\le\|x\|\le b\|x\|_1$ holds for all $x$.

Comment: @egreg: Yes that is the point. I can now only talk about existence of such $a$ and $b$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your answer for $a$ is quite tight enough yet. If you are allowed, it may be helpful to look at a case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for vectors $\bar{x} = [\: |x_1|,|x_2|,\dots\:]$ and $y=[\:1,1,\dots\:]$.

For "smallest" and "largest", it suffices to provide non-zero example vector(s) such that the inequalities become equality. Drawing a picture of the level sets of $|| \cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ might help.

Comment: To clarify, because this confused me for an embarrassingly long time just now, the example vectors must also be non-zero, so that you actually get a contradiction if you assume a smaller upper bound (or larger lower bound) exists.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: If we think this extreme case where $x_i=k,\forall i$ to satisfy the equality we need to have $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}$. Still, this does not guarantee that this particular value is the smallest.

Comment: It does, however, if you can find a non-zero vector (which you have) such that equality is held. Then, the existence of a larger $a$ would cause a contradiction!